# moodle phpmyadmin cannot log in

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, moodle

After installing moodle, cannot og in as root in phpmyadmin, i tried everything i found in google, but i just can log in with other user called "admin" who only have acces to 1 DB.
my authentication zone in config.inc.php look like this:

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
```

can someone help me to log in with root?

Comment: sorry for my bad english >.<

Comment: Try logging in from the command-line client to see if you actually have the correct username and password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same experience.It was resolved by Opening command Prompt as Admin.. It should work